# Does Mnesia have something like limit in MySQL?

Tags: database, erlang, mnesia

I need to read some information from Mnesia. How can I do this with limit?

Comment: Do you mean read all records?

Comment: This will be useful. http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2008-April/034630.html

Answer (score 0):

`ets` (Erlang Term Storage) which is the storage engine of `ram_copies` and `disc_copies` Mnesia tables provides functions which get **Limit** parameters:

- match(Tab, Pattern, Limit) -> {[Match], Continuation} | '$end_of_table'
- match_object(Tab, Pattern, Limit) -> {[Match], Continuation} | '$end_of_table'
- select(Tab, MatchSpec, Limit) -> {[Match], Continuation} | '$end_of_table'
- select_reverse(Tab, MatchSpec, Limit) -> {[Match], Continuation} | '$end_of_table'

You can use above functions for Mnesia tables with `ram_copies` and `disc_copies` table type.

#### Example:

```
-record(person, {name, age}).

select_persons_by_age(Age, Limit) ->
  ets:match(person, #person{name = '_', age = Age}, Limit).
```

Note that this way the **entire table** will be scanned for matching desired data up to the specified limit. This official [document](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/tablesDatabases.html) could be useful about its efficiency.